# Vapor pressure lowering

Tags: vapor-pressure, pressure

I have got this problem in my text book,

> Consider these three
>   mercury manometers. One of them
>   has 1 mL of water placed on top of the
>   mercury, another has 1 mL of a 1 m
>   urea solution placed on top of the
>   mercury, and the third one has 1 mL of
>   a 1 m NaCl solution placed on top of
>   the mercury. Identify X, Y, and Z with
>   these solutions.

[image]

I got the answer in answer sheet is X = ${H_2}O$ , Y = $NaCl$  and Z = ${(NH_2)}_2{CO}$ . Can any one please explain me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colligative_properties

Comment: @MaxW but i'm confused whether  Y = NaCl or not, i think  Z = NaCl is more preferable

Comment: NaCl splits into two ions thus has more colligative influence than urea which the molecule dissolves as one thing. Scale in drawing obviously greatly exaggerated.

Comment: @MaxW sorry i couldn't get it. Can you please write your answer with proper description ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer hings on the [colligative properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colligative_properties) of solutes. In essence solutes lower the vapor pressure of the solvent. NaCl splits into two ions (i.e. two solute "particles") and lowers the vapor pressure of water more than urea for which the whole molecule dissolves as one solute "particle."

If there was no liquid the Hg level would be higher than any of the three tubes shown since there would be a pure vacuum above the Hg.

The scale of the relative differences in drawing is obviously greatly exaggerated.

Comment: Interesting!! The problem statement says urea and the answer does give empirical formula for glucose. I didn't catch that.

Comment: sorry edited..:) so now Z = urea ?